# 2 hosts on same subnet route thru 3rd host?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

Here's the setup:

```
Host A : 192.168.0.5/24
Host B : 192.168.0.6/24
Host C : 192.168.0.1/24
```

All connected via switch.

I want to monitor traffic between A and B by setting a route on A and B to use C as their GW for each other.

I can get this to work fine if A and B are on different subnets, but was hoping there would be a way to do it with all on the same subnet.

S0 first I setup routes on both A and B by issuing

```
route add -host B gw C
```

(and vice versa for B)

On C i enable forwarding.  When i run wireshark on C, and then ping from A to B, I see the ping request come in from A, with A's MAC sent to C's MAC. then C retransmits using C's MAC to B's MAC.

A and B both have 'accept_redirects' off so that they are forced to use C.

Problem: pinging from A to B never works.  Wireshark on B never shows an incoming ping request.

Wireshark on C shows its being sent to B's ip/mac, but it looks like B never gets it, or its being filtered out somewhere below wireshark.

any hints?  what could be filtering out the packet?

Comment: Proxy ARP. Or Ettercap to implement ARP poisoning. Best option is to mirror the switch ports for A and B to C, but that isn't usually a feature on consumer grade networks.

Comment: Dont think proxy_arp will make a difference since A and B already know to send their packets to C.  C is forwarding them (according to Wireshark), but the receiving end does not show their receipt in wireshark.

Comment: Currently, can B ping C?

Comment: Yes, both A and B can ping C, and C and ping both. I'm wondering if there is some filtering happening down under somewhere in B ???? Firewalld is disabled. Rp_filter off (but shouldn't be an issue here anyway I don't think)

Answer (score 0):

Try [arpspoof](https://su2.info/doc/arpspoof.php) from the `dsniff` package.

It won't work if the two hosts can protect against ARP Poisoning since this is exactly how it works.

Shell 1

```
# Enable packet forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Tell A we are B
arpspoof -t hostA hostB
```

Shell 2

```
# Tell B we are A
arpspoof -t hostB hostA
```

Shell 3

```
# Watch the traffic
tshark -f 'host hostA and host hostB and not arp'
```

Comment: Not sure about this fix in my situation, because my routing box already sees the ping from A-to-B and forwards it to B's MAC, and vice verse.  The problem is wireshark on B never shows receipt of the request from A (even tho wireshark on  router shows forwarding to B's mac)

Comment: You said there is no routing, so the device is acting as a switch, and therefore susceptible to ARP spoofing per this solution. Without this your Host C won't see anything - that's exactly what switches are supposed to do.

Comment: There is an explicit static route on A and B to each other via C.

Comment: That is completely contradictory to the information provided in your question, where it says, "_Host A: 192.168.0.5/24 / Host B: 192.168.0.6/24 / Host C: 192.168.0.1/24_". Which is correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you might have missed this part, "S0 first I setup routes on both A and B by issuing

route add -host B gw C

(and vice versa for B)"

Comment: No. That's meaningless as they're all on the same subnet.

Comment: Well with the setup described, C does see the ping request from A-to-B, and C even tries forwarding it to B's MAC.  Same is true pinging B-to-A; C sees and forwards request.  So its not all meaningless; the setup does tell A to forward via C.  but maybe under the covers them being on the same subnet is why B is ignoring an ICMP request with C's MAC and A's IP.   Is there any documentation that describes this?  rp_filter is the closest thing i could find, but doesn't seem to apply here since a-to-b is the same route as b-to-a....

Comment: ICMP Redirect, probably. If you want to use the solution I've suggested, rip out those routes and go back to A, B, C being on the same subnet. `dsniff` sorts all that out.